# Why default Magento2 .gitignore file ignores composer.json, Gruntfile.js?

Tags: magento2, git

It's a simple question: why does Magento ignore by default package.json, Gruntfile.js and grunt-config.js files?
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/prod/config-reference-gitignore.html

I understand that for a production environment this should be the case, but when sharing my project with other developers, it's a problem not having these files. We could create a project config folder with these files and then copy them, but why does Magento prefer just ignoring them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@PaulGNU did you find an answer to this question?

Comment: I think the answer is because grunt is for local development, the gitignore is to ensure stuff doesn't go to production that isn't required

Comment: I didn't, sorry. So we need to keep in mind to share this files a part when sharing our project sources.